# How do you list all collections inside a database in mongodb and count the number of rows for each of them?

Tags: mongodb

How do you list all collections inside a database in mongodb and count the number of rows for each of them?

I have migrated my MongoDB db to SQL, but I need to compare the number of rows on each of the collection and associated table to see if there's a match and if there's no match find out why.

Is there an easy way to do this? I know there's a question for listing all collections, but I also need the number of rows.

Comment: Which [MongoDB driver](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/) are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, using the `Mongo Shell`, you can try running these commands:

1. `use databaseName`
2. `let collections = db.getCollectionNames();`
3. ``` collections.forEach(collection => {  const docsCount = db.runCommand({count: collection}); print(``${collection} ``` ``` ${docsCount.n}``) }) ```

This will print the number of documents in each collection in the database, on the Mongo Shell.